# How do I subtract sum of two integers from another integer and then increment it?

Tags: c++

How to subtract sum of x and y from z and then increment it in a single statement in C++

```
int main()
{
int x,y,z,p;
x=5;
y=6;
z=20;
p=z-(x+y)++;
cout<<"value of p="<<p;
}
```

it's showing error as value required as increment operand

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `x + y = z++`. Left hand side cannot be a summation!

Comment: You need to initialize `z` before you use it. Right now it's uninitialized, which means it will have an *indeterminate* value (that will seem random) and using it except to initialize it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As for your question, remember that assignment goes from the right to the left. The destination of the assignment is on the left side of the `=`. Furthermore, you mention *subtraction* but you don't subtract anything.

Comment: The problem is with `(x+y)++`. This article might help explain it: [Understanding lvalues and rvalues in C and C++](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   int x,y,f,z;
   f=(x=10, y=5, z=20, z-(x+y)+1);
   std::cout << "result is = "<<f ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract that sum, reduced by 1, using `-=` : `z -= (x + y - 1)`

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    x = 5;
    y = 6;
    z = 20;

    z -= (x + y - 1);

    std::cout << "value of z=" << z;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18725dc9ac027784

Answer (score -1):

Increment just means to add 1, hence `p=z-(x+y)+1;` is just as valid as using the Postfix Increment Operator